dataproc ERROR ClusterManager: Could not initialize cluster nodes
I have created in Dataproc a cluster with 1 master node and 5 workers.
When I run a PySpark job I get this error,

ERROR ClusterManager: Could not initialize cluster nodes
currentNodeIndex=null

I think the problem happens after the initialization of the spark session,
spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("HybridVectorSearch") \
        .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "200") \
        .config("spark.executor.memory", "20g") \
        .config("spark.executor.cores", "4") \
        .config("spark.driver.memory", "20g") \
        .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "10g") \
        .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true") \
        .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors", "2") \
        .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", "50") \
        .config("spark.executor.memoryOverhead", "2g") \
        .getOrCreate()
    
    dataset_rdd = read_bin_rdd(spark, dataset_path, TOTAL_DIM, NUM_PARTITIONS)
    queries_rdd = load_queries(spark, query_path)

    dataset = dataset_rdd.collect()
    dataset_broadcast = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(dataset)

I've tried to recreate the cluster multiple times with no luck.
